# stream.filter is not working for some objects in my List<Objects>, is there any solution or other method?

Tags: java, java-stream

I made a filter for a list of Objects and searching for the name of one objects in this list: `tables.getTable().stream().filter(p->p.geName().equals(referenceName)).findAny;`

The `referenceName` is not `null` and also the object that contains this name exist in the list, but it results an error, here is the result:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> comparator.complex.obj.comparison.XmlObjComparison.lambda$XmlObjectsComparison$8(XmlObjComparison.java:359)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(MatchOps.java:90)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1632)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.noneMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:538)
> at
> comparator.complex.obj.comparison.XmlObjComparison.XmlObjectsComparison(XmlObjComparison.java:359)
> at
> comparator.complex.obj.comparison.XmlObjComparison.test2(XmlObjComparison.java:584)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
> com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

what is possible? because in some cases it works and in some others it does not work!

Comment: Looks like either an object inside `tables.getTable()` or what `geName()` returns on one of them is null. You could filter for null elements before your current filter and reverse your filter (if you're sure `referenceName` is not null) as in `referenceName.equals(p->p.geName())` to avoid a NPE.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no it is not the case because i filtered the null before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Stream::peek` to debug the application and use additional filters or null check:

```java
tables.getTable() // some collection
    .stream()
    .peek(p -> System.out.println("1: p=" + Objects.toString(p))) // 
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // make sure p is not null
    .peek(p -> System.out.println("2: p.name=" + Objects.toString(p.getName()))) // 
    .filter(p -> Objects.equals(referenceName, p.getName()))
    .findAny();
```

---

Mere null check

```java
tables.getTable() // some collection
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> p != null && Objects.equals(referenceName, p.getName()))
    .findAny();
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
tables.getTable().stream().filter(p->p.geName().equals(referenceName)).findAny;
```

It must be `p.geName()` returning null. Try either `Objects.equals(referenceName, p.geName())` or `referenceName.equals(p.geName())` or put in a null check. Also, I assume that `findAny` is a method call but you excluded the parenthesis. Just to clarify: I'm not saying that `p` is null, but that the result of `p.geName()` might be null. If it is, then calling `.equals()` on it will obviously yield a `NullPointerException`.

If your problem is still not solved, you're going to have to provide more information, like how you are creating the stream, what you are trying to do, what the `p` variable even is and the structure of `p`'s class.

Comment: unfortunately it is not working still, p.getName() is not a null !
the objects is a List<Object>
Object contains many Values that one of them is 'Name'
when I use the get(index) it gave me the correct value (when you know the index) like 
tables.getTable.get(index).getName() it is working and giving the correct value! but when I put this in the streaming it return an error! it is so wierd for me!